# QStatusBar расположение элементов

Tags: python, pyqt5, qstatusbar

В статус баре элементы добавляются справа, а команда `statusBar().insertPermanentWidget()` – делает привязку в крайнюю левую позицию из имеющихся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:

1. Можно ли привязать элемент к левому краю рамки?  (не меняя размеры `StatusBar’а`, либо окна)
2. Можно ли  элемент распределить равномерно? (не меняя размеры `StatusBar’а`, либо окна)

p.s. Вопрос общий, весь код выкладывать смысла нет

```
#forma.py
self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

#main.py
self.excelCheckBox = QCheckBox('Весь список')
self.excelCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.state_changed)  
self.excelCheckBox.setChecked(True)

self.statusBar().insertPermanentWidget(1, self.excelCheckBox)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: На первый вопрос ответ можно найти в темке [Размеры QProgressBar в QStatusBar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435043/Размеры-qprogressbar-в-qstatusbar/1435051#1435051)