# Размеры QProgressBar в QStatusBar

Tags: python, pyqt5, qprogressbar, qstatusbar

Для меня явилось открытием, что  `ProgressBar`, находясь в `StatusBar’е`, растягивается в зависимости от размеров окна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Можно ли установить фиксированный размер `ProgressBar’а`, скованного рамками `StatusBar’а`, не меняя при этом размеры `StatusBar’а`, либо окна?

p.s. Вопрос общий, весь код выкладывать смысла нет

```
#main.py
self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100)
self.progress.setObjectName("progress")
self.progress.setStyleSheet('text-align: center; '                                     
             'min-height: 15px; max-height: 15px;')

self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.progress)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй параметр addPermanentWidget определяет растягивать ли этот элемент, и с каким весом, если можно растягивать несколько элементов. Если ни для одного элемента stretch не указан, то определяется автоматически, исходя из sizePolicy элементов (не документированно).

```
self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.progress, 0)
```

Разумеется, нужно чтобы был хотя бы один элемент с ненулевым stretch. Можно добавить пустой QWidget:

```
self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget( QtWidgets.QWidget(self), 1 )
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересная информация. Как раз то что искалось в теме  [QStatusBar расположение элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1434980/qstatusbar-расположение-элементов?noredirect=1#comment2559740_1434980)